# Svelte select specific object data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, svelte, sveltekit

I need help accessing specific objects in a JSON file based on a name value in Svelte.

I am using JSON as a data source and am able to pull it into my page and loop through it with each.

The JSON looks like so:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Project 1",
      "body": "Project 1 text"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Project 2",
      "body": "Project 2 text"
    }
  ]
```

I access the JSON like this:

```
<script context="module">
    export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
        const res = await fetch("https://amarton.github.io/amcom-portfolio-svelte/static/port.json");
        const projects = await res.json();
        return {
            props: {
                projects,
            }
        }
    }
 
</script>

<script>
    export let projects; 
</script>
```

And then loop through and display it like this:

```
       {#each projects as project}
            <h2>{project.title}</h2>
            <p>{project.body}</p>
        {/each}
```

I'd like to be able to access objects based on my assigned ids. For example, how do I grab JUST the object with the id of 2 and display its title and body in my page?

Sorry if this is a very basic question and thanks for much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not use `{#each}` and instead get the item in the JS. E.g. like this:

```js
$: project = projects.find(p => p.id == '2');
```

You now can reference `project` as is without the loop.

If you want a dynamic selection you can bind a `select` element to an ID like this:

```html
<script>
    export let projects = [];

    let id = '';
    $: project = projects.find(p => p.id == id);
</script>

<label>
    Project
    <select bind:value={id}>
        <option />
        {#each projects as p}
            <option value={p.id} label={p.title} />
        {/each}
    </select>
</label>

{#if project}
    <h2>{project.title}</h2>
    <p>{project.body}</p>
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4ceb1191121c4f469159c05f9edab590?version=3.49.0)

The reactive statement (`$:`) ensures that `project` is updated if `projects` or `id` changes.

Comment: Thanks so much, this got me there and taught me a bit more along the way.